# Select Command sometimes gets the same row

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, database

I have a project in C# which gets data from MySQL Database table and updating column with (`StatusID = 5`). It searches for a `row` with `StatusID = 4`.

Let me show you the flow:

```
SELECT * FROM ACCOUNTS WHERE STATUSID = 4
// After that I assign an object with the data i got.
UPDATE ACCOUNTS SET STATUSID = 5 WHERE ACCOUNTNAME = '#ACCOUNTNAME'
```

This flow takes few ms, but the problem is this project is running over 700 PC at the same time, So it sometimes reach the same part of the codes at the same time, so what happen is 1-5 PCs gets the same account. So i need something like a `trigger` or to make when i `Select` an account, it takes few seconds if not changed to be selected again something like that.

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Looks like you need transactions

Comment: @bradbury9 , Not sure what does transactions in this situation means!

Comment: You should read about [transactions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html). Also make sure to use `select ... for update`. But first read about transactions.

Comment: @GameHackerPM using SQL transactions to avoid the concurrency of two clients accesing same data and having 'phantom' reads https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-transactions.html

Comment: Thanks for helping, I will check it and learn about it, Can one of you also put an example for my situation as answer, so i can give him +REP and to check if it's working as well, will close the question.

Comment: Added a response with c# code from the MSDN, for SQL transactions you could check @Solarflare link or my previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need transactions in your code.

You can start a transaction in your SQL code or in your c# code, both do similar things. In your case looks like you need a c# transaction https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86773566(v=vs.110).aspx

That being said, you should also check the isolation level, to make sure the behaviour is the desired one https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.isolationlevel(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Is this ok?
It is not the answer for your question but if you cant not update you know it was already changed

```
UPDATE ACCOUNTS SET STATUSID = 5 WHERE ACCOUNTNAME = '#ACCOUNTNAME' AND STATUSID = 4
```

Comment: Thanks for help, but that's not a solution! :)